# Aggregate Data by date

Tags: r

I'm working on the following dataframe:

```
VAL1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "BB", "DD", "AA", "DD")
D01012016 <- c(2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 8, 12, 4)
D02012016 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4)
D03022016 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7)
D05022016 <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2,3, 3, 6)
D03032016 <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1)
D01042016 <- c(2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 8, 12, 4)
D02042016 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4)
D03042016 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7)
D05042016 <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2,3, 3, 6)
D05052016 <- c(2, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
D23062016 <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1)
D05072016 <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 2,3, 3, 6)
D03082016 <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1)
D01092016 <- c(2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 8, 12, 4)
D12092016 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4)
D05102016 <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1)
D21112016 <- c(2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 8, 12, 4)
D13122016 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4)
df <- data.frame(D01012016, D02012016, D03022016,D05022016,D03032016,D01042016,D02042016,D03042016,D05042016,D05052016,D23062016,D05072016,D03082016,D01092016,D12092016,D05102016,D21112016,D13122016)
```

Colnames are dates in the format Dddmmyyyy, i need to group data, mantaining in the first column `VAL1` (repeated values of VAL must remain separated) and group its monthly values (second `colnames` on have to be the months name, and data has to be aggregated with sum() function).
Final dataset must have the same number of rows( and all VAL1 must be in the same position) and having only 12 columns (one per month)

Comment: What do you mean by aggregated? What is your expected output? Also, there must be many answers on aggregating time series data in R.

Comment: @Gopala, Obtain one column for each month (in case of montly) or one for each quarter (in case of quarterly). I know, i'm just a beginner with R and i didn't find anything where I had to aggregate by colnames and in which dates had a char before the real date

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, hi! :) No, the originary dataframe has to change just for the number of column,  dayly values has to be groupes by month with the sum(). So number of rows will remain immutate, but columns will be only 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the reshape2 (tidyr or reshape could has also been used) package to reform your data frame and the dplyr library to summarize your results:

```
df <- data.frame(VAL1, D01012016, D02012016, D03022016,D05022016,D03032016,D01042016,D02042016,D03042016,D05042016,D23062016,D05072016,D03082016,D01092016,D12092016)

library(reshape2)
ndf<-melt(df)
ndf$date<-as.Date(ndf$variable, format="D%d%m%Y")

library(dplyr)
summarize(group_by(ndf, VAL1, cut(ndf$date, breaks ="1 month")), sum(value))
```

It is difficult to work with the your by column format, thus it is easier to convert from the wide format to a long format.  VAL1 is carried from the melt command.  If you are interested in quarterly results just change from 1 month breaks to three month breaks.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is harder than it seems, i can't use merge function because i need duplicate datas in the first column...i re edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: Ok,thanks, but I have one question: after using melt() how can I return to the same structure of the first dataframe? Same number of rows but only 12 columns

Comment: The dcast command in the reshape2 library can convert from long to wide format.  Depending of your column name the formula will be something like: dcast(finaldf, VAL1~month)

Comment: Perfect..the only problem is that using `summarize(group_by(ndf, VAL1, cut(ndf$date, breaks ="1 month")), sum(value))` I obtain a df containing only two columns, one containing the months the other the sums, but only 12 rows, as if it just aggregated by month without taking in consideration VAL1 (i'd like to obtain 12 rows for each VAL1)

Comment: You should have obtained 3 columns from the summarize command, entitled: VAL1,  cut(ndf$date,  breaks = "1 month") and sum(value).  My results have 3 columns by 32 rows, I am not sure where your results are diverging.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var="VAL1")[, date := as.Date(variable, "D%d%m%Y")][
          ,.(Sum=sum(value)) , by = .(VAL1, grp = cut(date, breaks= "1 month"))]
```